# BLE itag alarm on every xx hours in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im trying to develop app for iOS in swift language that will on remote notification trigger alarm (beep) on BLE iTag. For now i can make it to work when app is in background state. But i would like to make it work also when user force-quit or swipe away app. Is it possible? Is it possible to keep iTag connected when user force-quit app?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to receive remote notifications or do anything if your app is not running.